# Okcupid.com (can find matches without accessing a database!?)

Tags: c++, mysql, database, webserver

I'm doing a research project on a popular dating site called: [OkCupid](http://www.okcupid.com/about/technology)
I would like to talk about how the database is used.
After reading this explanation from the Co-Founder of the site, I became very confused.
The statements:

> when a user performs a match search on OkCupid, we have to do the
>   following:
>
> -Retrieve **(from somewhere not the DB)** their question answers, their ideal match's answers, and their question importances. On average,
>   each user on OkCupid has 250 questions answered in 3 parts.
>   -Figure out who qualifies for their search, typically a very complicated query across a few million users. On average, tens of
>   thousands of people qualify, and we need to figure out who they are
>   **without hitting the DB.**

How do they do all this without consulting a database??
[Here is a link to the post](http://www.quora.com/OkCupid/Is-OkCupid-programmed-in-only-C)
I appreciate any explanations as to how they do things there

Comment: If they hit a cache, they're not hitting their database... That's about all I can think of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For that frequently accessed information, it may be backd by a database but also stored in a distributed memory cache (e.g. [Memcached](http://www.memcached.org/)).

When a user updates their answer or answers a new question, it would update the cache and the database so the database never has to get queried.

They could somehow access a user's answers or specific answers based on a cache key and asynchronously query multitudes of users and compare answers.

Just a guess though.

Comment: That's pretty much right, the match system keeps everything in memory. Chris answered in response to a comment on that post: http://qr.ae/IIeFm